# Access denied to all authorised users of Windows 7

Tags: permissions, windows-7, authorization

By mistake I denied all permissions to a folder to all authorised users group on my windows 7 machine. This is a personal laptop and I am admin on the machine. Machine has only one account that's mine. I tried a lot to retrieve my access on the folder but still not able to open any file present in the folder. I even formatted my machine and reinstalled windows 7 OS but it didn't help. Please provide some solution to the issue.

Comment: This is a programming Q+A site

Answer (score 0):

A/ 
You first have to open your computer case 
remove battery, then disconnect AC-plug anyway, 
completely remove the hard drive

Advice: remember how you do, and be careful because you'll have to redo the whole in reverse order later!
Of course, you may also need assistance if you never have open your personal laptop before...

B/ 
Mount it into an "USB dock".
That kind of useful tool costs around $30, and may accept both 2" and 3" hard drives.

C/ 
Then, connect that USB dock to another Windows computer.
Open Explorer, you'll see your hard drive as a new drive
Let's name it E: (it may be D: or F: as well)

D/ 
Access to your folder's *parent folder* :

- if "problematic_folder" was on the desktop, you have to reach E:\Users\yourprofilname\desktop\
- if "problematic_folder" was on your Documents folder, open E:\Users\yourprofilname\
- if "problematic_folder" is directly on the root, then simply open E:\

E/ 
As you have messed up with security privileges, you now have to become the owner :
Right-click on folder ~ properties ~ security tab ~
advanced button ~ owner tab >> modify button ~
other users or groups ~ enter EVERYONE ~ OK ~ select EVERYONE ~ OK

A "Windows security" warning appears ~ click OK ~ OK ~ OK

F/ 
Anew, access again your problematic_folder, 
right-click ~ properties ~ security tab ~
one left-click on each users/groups (authentified users, system, adminstrators, users, etc)
modify button ~ make sure you remove all REFUSE ACL ~ Apply
add FULL ACCESS if needed ~ OK

G/ 
Do the same permissions' modifications for all users/groups (at least authentified users, system, adminstrators, users, etc)

H/
Once finish, eject USB dock from host computer.
Remove your hard drive from the USB dock,
plug it into its initial place in YOUR computer, 
connect AC-plug (plus battery if necessary),
switch computer on.

I/
Your Windows loads, open your usual Win session, 
access your problematic_folder, you normally got full access :)

Last but not least: all sensible data MUST be saved in another place! An external harddrive is a perfect solution!